# Get the integral symbol provided by the minionint option of the minionpro package for use with LuaLaTeX

Tags: symbols, luatex, minionpro, integral

As the title mentions, I'm looking to get the integral symbol that is activated when using the `minionint` option of the `MinionPro` package, without having to install it. It's possible? I'm not sure which way to go. I am using the Minion Pro `.otf` fonts and I have copied the code referring to integrals from the `MinionPro` package, but no change occurs in the integral symbol. What is missing?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=./fuentes/minion/,
   UprightFont=*-Regular.otf,
   BoldFont=*-Bold.otf,
   ItalicFont=*-Italic.otf,
   BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic.otf
   ]{MinionPro}

\newfontface\Swash{MinionPro-Italic}[
Path=./fuentes/minion/,
 Extension = .otf,
 Contextuals=Swash]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsw}{\Swash}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\makeatletter

% integrals
%\newcommand\Mn@load@integrals{}

\newcommand\Mn@Decl@Minion@Ints{%
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolFI}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolFI}{m}{it}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@opticals5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@opticals6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@opticals7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@opticals8
   <9-10> MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@opticals9
  <10-12> MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@opticals10
  <12->   MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@opticals12
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolFI}{b}{it}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@bold\Mn@minionint@opticals5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@bold\Mn@minionint@opticals6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@bold\Mn@minionint@opticals7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@bold\Mn@minionint@opticals8
   <9-10> MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@bold\Mn@minionint@opticals9
  <10-12> MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@bold\Mn@minionint@opticals10
  <12->   MnSymbolFI\Mn@minionint@bold\Mn@minionint@opticals12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{intsymbols}  {U}{MnSymbolFI}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{intsymbols}{bold}{U}{MnSymbolFI}{b}{it}
\let\varint\tint
\let\variint\tiint
\let\variiint\tiiint
\let\variiiint\tiiiint
\let\varidotsint\tidotsint
\let\varlandupint\tlandupint
\let\varlanddownint\tlanddownint
\let\varstrokedint\tstrokedint
\let\varoint\toint
\let\varoiint\toiint
\let\varrcirclerightint\trcirclerightint
\let\varlcirclerightint\tlcirclerightint
\let\varrcircleleftint\trcircleleftint
\let\varlcircleleftint\tlcircleleftint
\let\varsumint\tsumint
\DeclareMathSymbol\tint            \mathop{intsymbols}{112}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tiint           \mathop{intsymbols}{114}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tiiint          \mathop{intsymbols}{116}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tiiiint         \mathop{intsymbols}{118}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tidotsint       \mathop{intsymbols}{120}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tlandupint      \mathop{intsymbols}{122}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tlanddownint    \mathop{intsymbols}{124}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tstrokedint     \mathop{intsymbols}{126}
\DeclareMathSymbol\toint           \mathop{intsymbols}{128}
\DeclareMathSymbol\toiint          \mathop{intsymbols}{130}
\DeclareMathSymbol\trcirclerightint\mathop{intsymbols}{132}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tlcirclerightint\mathop{intsymbols}{134}
\DeclareMathSymbol\trcircleleftint \mathop{intsymbols}{136}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tlcircleleftint \mathop{intsymbols}{138}
\DeclareMathSymbol\tsumint         \mathop{intsymbols}{140}
\let\intop\tint
\let\ointop\toint
}
% \Mn@load@integrals

\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is Minion Pro font and \textsw{This is the Swashes}
\[\int  f dx\]
\end{document}
```